# Is it a good choice to define my own JSON util class like this?

Tags: java, json

```
package utils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JSONUtils {

    public static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static String toJSON(Object o, String... fields) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (String f : fields) {
            try {
                Field field = o.getClass().getField(f);
                map.put(f, field.get(o));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return gson.toJson(map);
    }

    public static String toJSONForList(List<?> objects, String... fields) {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Object o : objects) {
            list.add(toJSON(o, fields));
        }
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }
}
```

**Note** : I need to convert list to JSON very often.

Answer (score 3):

Are you changing the fields that you expose from your objects depending on certain conditions?

On the whole it would be best to use reflection only as a last gasp. Gson works fine with collections in general see the documentation over at [Google](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).

If you want to exclude some fields from serialization then you can use the `@Expose` annotation, as documented [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization). This requires you to annotate all fields that you want to serialize with the `@Expose` annotation, and to use a builder to instantiate your Gson Object like so:

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

In general try to limit how much you are working with the type `Object` and reduce as far as possible your use of reflection.